# Backfilling columns by groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv like

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,,
1,2,30,100
1,2,40,100
4,5,,
4,5,60,200
4,5,70,200
8,9,,
```

In row 1 and row 4 C value is missing (`NaN`). I want to take their value from row 2 and 5 respectively. (First occurrence of same A,B value).

If no matching row is found,  just put 0 (like in last line)
Expected op:

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,30,
1,2,30,100
1,2,40,100
4,5,60,
4,5,60,200
4,5,70,200
8,9,0,
```

using `fillna` I found `bfill: use NEXT valid observation to fill gap` but the `NEXT` observation has to be taken logically (looking at col A,B values) and not just the upcoming C column value

Comment: `but the NEXT observation has to be taken logically (looking at col A,B values) ` can you elaborate?

Comment: suppose line 5 had 4,7,70,100 and then line 6 was 4,5,60,200, even then 60 should be placed at line line 4 column C and not 70. Because line 6 (matches 4,5) but not line 5 (4,7). I hope I am clear

Comment: thanks @COLDSPEED it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to call `df.groupby` on `A` and `B` first and then apply the `bfill` function:

```
In [501]: df.C = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda x: x.C.bfill()).reset_index(drop=True)

In [502]: df
Out[502]: 
   A  B   C      D
0  1  2  30    NaN
1  1  2  30  100.0
2  1  2  40  100.0
3  4  5  60    NaN
4  4  5  60  200.0
5  4  5  70  200.0
6  8  9   0    NaN
```

You can also group and then call `dfGroupBy.bfill` directly (I think this would be faster):

```
In [508]: df.C = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.bfill().fillna(0).astype(int); df
Out[508]: 
   A  B   C      D
0  1  2  30    NaN
1  1  2  30  100.0
2  1  2  40  100.0
3  4  5  60    NaN
4  4  5  60  200.0
5  4  5  70  200.0
6  8  9   0    NaN
```

If you wish to get rid of `NaN`s in `D`, you could do:

```
df.D.fillna('', inplace=True)
```